# IPv6 address of a computer on local network does not start with fe80

Tags: networking, ipv6

I have a local network of computers and occasionally, after a restart, a computer gets a new IPv6 address that is not a link-local address (i.e. it doesn't start with fe80). This causes the computer's access to my database server to be rejected, since the DB is configured to only accept connections from local network.

I can fix this issue by unplugging the affected computer's ethernet cables and re-plugging them (I have 2 ethernet ports per computer), but this is a less than ideal solution.

I want to understand how a computer on local network could have a non-link-local IPv6 address and fix this problem.

Comment: Could you tell what the address starts with? Maybe we could get a clue what's going on. Does the interface lose its link-local address when it gets the mysterious new address, or does the new address appear in addition to the link-local address?

Comment: Most likely the network card is flaky. But why do you need IPv6 for a local network? IPv4 is enough and is much less problematic.

Comment: You can have more than one IPv6 address on a particular interface.  Why not just hard code a static IP of your choosing?